# Softphone answer event in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I want to make a web interface that prints out a form that needs to be filled.
The problem is that i want to print out the form only when a call is answered by a softphone.

What event should i listen for?

I'm using Asterisk 1.6 and I get all the events in XML using AsterClick.

thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsterClick is an excellent choice as it is the only 
event based Asterisk AMI /(XML)/JavaScript interface
on the planet that can propagates those events to
JavaScript AS they occur!! All others use polling,

As to your question...

During your AsterClick development,when your JavaScript inherits from the 
wSocket class, you should implement the method(s) 
your_wSocket.wSocketsReceiveString(String) and/or
your_wSocket.wSocketsReceiveXML(XMLdocument).

These wSocket methods should be documented on the AsterClick site http://asterclick.drclue.net
with more help being available in the forums http://forums.drclue.net/viewforum.php?f=13.

These functions can be used to monitor the XML command and event flow in real time
and represents all the data Asterisk AMI provides.

I tend to route this information to an autoscrolling widget with a handy [clear]
button near by.

By pressing your [clear] button and then interacting with your
phones while examining the event flow, you
should be able to pick out the events and related data for
any automation sequence.

As to jQuery, I know that there are jQuery/Asterclick projects
running out there, including a real-time HUD system that manages
calls,conferencing,parking,queues, etc.

The AsterClick client SDK is also squarely aimed at HTML5 and running
on an ever increasing range of devices as the HTML5 features required are
implemented.

You can also use the AsterClick "WBEA" tool to deploy your HTML5
AsterClick applications as desktop executables for Windows,Linux.

Anyways I Hope some of that helps.

Comment: Too bad AsterClick seems to have disappeared from the net :-(

Answer (score 0):

You should capture events from AMI, you can use Adhearsion for this (Adhearsion can be also connected to a Rails app):
https://github.com/adhearsion/adhearsion

or PAMI if you prefer PHP:
https://github.com/marcelog/PAMI